# How can I find where files are used as links in html pages?

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a static website where versions of old pages are still stored in the root. I want to find these pages and look if they are used in some link somewhere in the root's files. 
So I made a list of all the files inside the root using powershell's command `ls -R -Name` and store it on a file 'filelist.txt' and now I have something like:

```
directory1
directory2
5s.htm
5s.html
5s_introduction.htm
...
images\icons
images\icons\linkedin.png
images\icons\project-slider-arrow-left.png
images\icons\project-slider-arrow-right.png
```

I now want to look where these files are used, so I thought I could use a simple script in python (as I don't know windows' powershell) where it takes a line from the list and then look for occurences in each html page inside root.
To extract only the file name I then tried this regex on notepad++:

```
[^\\^\n]+\.[a-z]{0,4}
```

and seemed to work...(^\n is to exclude all lines that represent directories)
Second step, I tried to adapt this Python lines i found on stackoverflow:

```
import re
with open('filelist.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        m = re.match('([^\\^\n]+\.[a-z]{0,4})', l)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

but it returns me strings completely wrong, full of spaces or single letters, like if regex is wrong.
Then I thought I could use regex result as a variable and check it somehow on each html pages on my root directory, but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sure that the file names contain `'.'`, each path can be split on `'\'` and checked if it contains `'.'`. Also, stripping each line would remove new line characters.

```
with open('filelist.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
      l= l.strip()
      if '.' in l.split('\\')[-1]:
          print l.split('\\')[-1]
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 5s.htm
> 5s.html
> 5s_introduction.htm
> linkedin.png
> project-slider-arrow-left.png
> project-slider-arrow-right.png
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
([\d+\w+\.\\\-])+
```

Comment: It doesn't work... it prints me the last letter of the file extension